MAUI Label gets not updated by InvokeOnMainThreadAsync
I am new to MAUI. I am using the default MAUI project from VS2022 (Button Click)
Instead of only clicking the button and update its .Text, I get data via an Event.
But the text in the UI never gets updated. Even when debugging, even after the assignment of .Text, the debugger shows always the 'old' value at CounterBtn.Text.
What is wrong?
private void OnMessageReceived(object? sender, PioneerEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnMessageReceived {0} {1}", e.FunctionName, e.PropertyValue);
    CounterBtn.Text = $"Pio {e.FunctionName} {e.PropertyValue}";

    MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
    {
        // Code to run on the main thread
        CounterBtn.Text = $"Pio {e.FunctionName} {e.PropertyValue}";
    });
}

Expecting: Update if GUI

is OnMessageReceived in the code-behind of your page?

please add full code, i.e. view where the button is, how is this event triggered etc. As this looks right. Guessing the console.WriteLine works

Please show all of the relevant code. What is your OnMessageReceived event handler hooked up to? When is it invoked? Did you put a breakpoint on the line that updates the Text property of your label to see if it gets called at all?

Please ensure that the click event of the button is correctly bound to the OnMessageReceived method. In addition, check whether the FunctionName and PropertyValue properties in PioneerEventArgs are valid by adding breakpoint.
